# Templated Quick/Merge Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, quicksort

I've been trying to write a templated function in C++ that can accept an array of any type and sort it. The sort used has to be a quick sort or a merge sort, but I'm having a lot of trouble with implementing either of these, as a quick sort header usually comes with a top and bottom parameter, and a merge sort comes with a first and last parameter.  My function header looks like this: void mySort(T *array, int n)

So far I have this:

```
template <typename T>
void sort(T *a, int n)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = n-1;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = a[(n-1)/2];
  while (i <= j){
    while (a[i] < pivot)
       i++;
    while (a[j] > pivot)
       j--;
    if (i<=j){
       tmp = a[i];
       a[i] = a[j];
       a[j] = a[i];
       i++;
       j--;
    }
  }

  if(0<j)
    sort(a, j);
  /*
  if(i<right)
    sort(
  */
}
```

I was trying to use a recursive call to sort, but I couldn't figure out how to call recursive for the right partition created, without a different parameter list.

Comment: you already know that both sorts need the first and last parameters, still you code don't have them, only array and size. Why?

Comment: You need to also stop the recursion when n gets too small.  For example when `j==1` you satisfied `0<j` but really don't want to sort that one element.

Comment: If you ignore any knowledge you might have about where the pivot element ended up, and ignore any termination of recursion issues, then the second sort would be `sort(a+j,n-j);`.  (Not saying you should necessarily ignore those things, just answering what you seem to be asking).

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the actual question: your code would benefit from factoring the partition code out of the body of the function! That way, you'd essentially call partition to determine the mid-point between the two arrays to be called, i.e., you'd have something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void sort(T* a, int n) {
    T* mid = partition(a, n);
    // ...
}
```

The idea is that `[a, mid)` contains all elements sorting smaller than the pivot and `[mid, a + n)` contains all elements sorting equal or greater than the pivot. All what remains is

1. Call `sort()` recursively with the two array, i.e.,

   ```
   sort(a, mid - a);
   sort(mid, (a + n) - mid);
   ```
2. Make sure `sort()` terminates if the array obtained is small than 2.

Of course, if you want your Quick Sort to be *quick* you'll also need to pull half a dozen or so tricks. Like:

1. Use [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) to guarantee the complexity is `O(n lg n)` (e.g. together with Merge Sort).
2. Use Insertion Sort on small ranges.
3. Use an implementation of partition and insertion sort taking advantage of suitable sentinels.
4. Sort really sort ranges directly.

One of the things which oddly is rather futile to play with is choice of a pivot. As far as I can tell, using the middle element works as well as any more advanced technique (assuming optimizations like those mentioned above are implemented).

Comment: @rcgldr: sure - the original paper almost certainly used an array with indices. It turns out that using pointers actually _does_ simply algorithms like `partition()` and `qsort()`.

Comment: Deleted my prior comment. For this particular scheme, when the recursive calls are made,  (i - j) == 1 or (i - j) == 2, depending on the values next to the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the called function from the recursive function:

```
// recursive function
template <typename T>
void quicksort(T *a, int lo, int hi)
{
    // ...
}

// called function    
template <typename T>
void sort(T *a, int n)
{
    if(n < 2)return;
    quicksort(a, 0, n-1);
}
```